# redirect sub pages to new domain using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have used

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to successfully redirect from `http://olddomain.com` to `http://newdomain.com`. However the sub-pages `http://olddomain.com/subpage` still does not redirect to `http://newdomain.com/subpage`

How can it be done?

Comment: Is the subpage inside of a directory, and does that directory have a `.htaccess` file in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution would probably be to place the following rule before the RewriteEngine on line:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*) http://newdomain.com$1
```

This should bypass any redirect rules or conflicts you may have and force everything to redirect.